# How can I use React Router's withRouter HOC inside my own higher order component (HOC)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a higher order component which uses the `location.search` prop provided by React Router to construct a `queryParams` object and pass it as a prop to its wrapped component.

```
function withQueryParams(WrappedComponent) {
    return (props) => {
        const queryParams = myUtils.parseParams(props.location.search); // props.location provided by React Router
        const newProps = {
            ...props,
            queryParams: queryParams
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...newProps} />
    }
}

export default withQueryParams
```

And I'd use it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { ... }

export default withQueryParams(MyComponent)
```

And of course I'd wrap `MyComponent` in a route:

```
<Route path="/mycomponent" component={MyComponent} />
```

But going back to my `withQueryParams` HOC, I'd like to ensure that `props.location` is always available, meaning I'd like it always to have props from React Router. Enter `withRouter`, which is itself a HOC provided by React Router that you can use to make those props available.

What would be the best way to use `withRouter` inside my `withQueryParams` HOC to ensure that `props.location` is available?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation for the <Route> component (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component), any component rendered by a <Route> component is passed three props: match, location, history. These are the sought after props, and withRouter has I believe the use of providing these props when the component in question is not the one directly rendered by a <Route> component.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The goal here is for `withQueryParams` to not have this implicit dependency on React Router props. It shouldn't break when it is used on a component that isn't rendered by a `<Route>`. That's why I want to wrap it in `withRouter` so it always has those props available, even in cases where it's not within context of an actual `<Route>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function withQueryParams(WrappedComponent) {
        return withRouter((props) => {
           const queryParams = myUtils.parseParams(props.location.search); // props.location provided by React Router
           const newProps = {
               ...props,
               queryParams: queryParams
           }

           return <WrappedComponent {...newProps} />
        })
}

export default withQueryParams
```

Comment: Couldn't you achieve the same result without declaring `realQueryParams`? What if you just wrapped the `return (props) ...` in `withRouter`? I.e. `return withRouter((props) => ...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your component with both the HOCs namely `withRouter` and `withQueryParams`. You can use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to wrap your components with these HOCs. I've created a sandbox for this. https://codesandbox.io/s/y493w29lz

First, Hit the https://y493w29lz.codesandbox.io/main. This will display following output on the screen.

```
MainComponent
SubComponent
"No Query Params available"
```

Now, Try passing a query parameter e.g. https://y493w29lz.codesandbox.io/main?query=hello. You can see that the query parameters are printed on the screen.

```
MainComponent
SubComponent
Query Params = {"query":"hello"}
```

Here, The component `SubComponent` is not rendered by the `Route` but it is receiving the query parameters as we have wrapped this component using the `withRouter` and `withQueryParms` HOCs.

```
export const SubComponent = compose(
  withRouter,
  withQueryParams
)(SubComponentView);
```

Now, If you render the `SubComponent` only by hitting the URL https://y493w29lz.codesandbox.io/sub?query=hello. It will display the following output.

```
SubComponent
Query Params = {"query":"hello"}
```

Hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed reply. Yes, I know I could wrap `withQueryParams` inside `withRouter` at the component level (`MainComponent` and `SubComponent` in your case), but my question was how to include `withRouter` *inside* the `withQueryParams.js` file, so it's sort of one encapsulated unit. That way I don't have to worry about wrapping it with `withRouter` every time I use it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, That totally makes sense. @nschwan94's answer does exactly that. :)